Kotlin serializer: Include binary data "as is"
I have an object that I want to serialize:
@Serializable
class Test(
    override val name: String,
    override val data: ByteArray
) {

    fun toBytes(): ByteArray = Json.encodeToString(this).encodeToByteArray()
}

This obviously serializes data into a String representation of the ByteArray.
// assume data = "test".toByteArray()
// then the serialized object will be
{
 "name": "somename"
 "data": "[116,101,115,116]"
}

Which now turns data from being 4 bytes into 17 bytes. How do serialize this data correctly? I would prefer to keep data as ByteArray as opposed to trying to turn data to String
EDIT:
Replying to @sweeper:
It is hard to explain what I mean, but the final serialized object could look like this:
"{
 \"name\": \"somename\",
 \"data\":".toByteArray() +
 data 
+ "\"}".toByteArray()

I was hoping Kotlin would have a similar mechanism in place where it would just "paste" the ByteArray in place.
Yes I can change the entire code to use Base64, but that's not what I am asking about.

Assuming data is just any arbitrary binary data, we can't store it as is in the JSON as JSON doesn't support binary data. Please read about the base64 encoding.

@broot Base64 came to my mind, but I was wondering if maybe a custom serializer would get around that...?

So your desired result is most likely not valid JSON, and no, a custom serialiser would not get around that. What is not JSON is just not JSON. Where are you sending this data to? Does the receiver even understand this custom format you just invented?

JSON is a text representation of data, so you will have trouble representing raw binary data without relying on some encoding like suggested by @broot . No Json decoder won't properly understand binary data embedded in Json. If you want efficient binary serialization, you should try to use a binary format, like Bson or protobuf.

Please note this is not a limitation of Kotlin or its serialization library. This is a limitation of JSON. We can easily write a serializer which puts binary data to the output and... breaks the JSON format.

If you would like to optimise for data size and you have control over the data format, consider using a binary format like protobuf.

Base64 is the most efficient and viable way to get a byte stream into the JSON format.  If you need something more efficient than Base64, then you cannot use JSON (and might consider e.g. protobuf as suggested by @Sweeper).

@Sweeper I have never said I have to use JSON. I am in control of both decoding and encoding.

@kristyna If you are able to control persistence try to use classic Java Externalizable API.

What you have to do in a situation like this, if the data is large, is store the data alongside the json. Basically a hybrid approach. It is a PIA because you'll likely have to build one yourself(which I am in the process of doing).
Basically store your binary data at the top of the file using the standard method that one would do in C/C++ (I'm working on writing a binary serializer that does just this for Kotlin that can be plugged in but I'm having to learn as I go). This might require some additional structure but can be manually done by just using File write(tracking the struct is the PIA part which is why I'm working on the binary serialization).
If you know all the array types you are serializing then what I would do is simply create a custom serializer for them
Alternatively you could use cbor. this might require some preprocessing of your classes.
Then basically use cbor to write your binary data at the top of the file(or bottom) then json at the bottom. Storing a position to the json location for easy retrieval.
Alternatively you could just write out the bytes in place but you will have to patch things up and write custom serializers for the data arrays(which isn't difficult but it's all a mess to work with.
If you can deal with cbor then just use cbor. IMO, the only reason to use json is to make editing the file easily doable which is why I chose to do it(it would still be work in my case since I am compressing my arrays).
// To be able to serialize ByteArray: Annotate with @Serializable(with = ByteArraySerializer::class)
object ByteArraySerializer : KSerializer<ByteArray> {
    override val descriptor: SerialDescriptor = PrimitiveSerialDescriptor("ByteArray", PrimitiveKind.STRING)
    @OptIn(ExperimentalSerializationApi::class)
    override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, value: ByteArray) { encoder.encodeString(value.size.toString() + ":" + value.contentHashCode()) }
    override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): ByteArray { return decoder.decodeString().toByteArray() }
}

e.g., gives
{
"dataTest1": "0:1",
"dataTest2": "52:1577655441"
}
for
@Serializable(with = ByteArraySerializer::class) var dataTest1: ByteArray = emptyArray<Byte>().toByteArray(),
@Serializable(with = ByteArraySerializer::class) var dataTest2: ByteArray = ByteArray(52).apply { this[0] = 53; this[22] = 123 }

You could just store an empty string or water
The idea is that after you decode your json you have to go back and fill in the missing information which was stored somewhere else.
If you store the data using cbor then it is quite easy except that you have to somehow make cbor and json be disjoint(not sure if you can annotate for a specific serializer or type).
If you are ok with using two files then you could have the json part and then the cbor part and it would almost be seemless to use if you could get the serialization of json to be disjoint from cbor
Alternatively you could directly encode the data with some hacky stuff but it wouldn't be valid json. E.g., you could use the code above but simply have it write out the ByteArray's bytes and length and some id/token to search for. Then when you load the json you have to replace the byte array with a shorter correct version for the serializer to decode correctly then replace that with the original bytes.
Either way you won't win. Json should have had a "blob" like type that let you use bytes directly but they didn't and it's impossible to add it since it would break every json parser out there.
